# Replicating the function of a for loop using only bitwise operators

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to replicate the function of a loop using only bitwise and certain operators including `!` `~` `&` `^` `|` `+` `<<` `>>`

```
int loop(int x) {
   for (int i = 1; i < 32; i += 2)
     if ((x & (1 << i)) == 0)
       return 0;
   return 1; 
}
```

Im unsure however how to replicate the accumulating nature of a loop using just these operators. I understand shifting `<<` `>>` will allow me to multiply and divide. However manipulation using `!` `~` `&` `^` `~` has proven more difficult. Any Tips?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Edit:
I understand how the addition of bits can be achieved, however not how such an output can be achieved without first calling a while or for loop.

Comment: First think about what the function is actually doing - it's testing all the odd-numbered bits to see if they are all 1. So how would you do that in a single operation using bitwise operators ? (Think masks.)

Comment: @PaulR ok, so lets say I create a mask with all even number bits set to 1 and compare it to a given value, if ((value & bit_mask) == 0) to check if every value truly is odd 0x55 would give me a value to compare with. I would be using if as well as == however.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are trying to obtain. Currently the function returns 1 if all odd numbered bits in x is 1 - otherwise it returns 0. I don't see how that replicates the function of a loop. Can you describe what you expect from the function.

Comment: @Silverfin: your logic is a bit off - you probably want to use a mask of all odd bits (`0xaaaaaaaa`), since these are the bits you are interested in. Then the function would just be `return (n & mask) == mask;` (you don't need an `if`). If you can't use `==` then think about how to implement that with further bitwise operations.

Comment: @4386427 It is using a for loop and if statement to iterate through until it returns a 1 no? Im unsure how to go through each number using only bitwise operators, ie no for or if statement.

Comment: @Silverfin - So you are trying to write another function which generates the same result as the current function but solely by use of the mentioned operators. Is that it?

Comment: @4386427 correct, apologies for not being clear.

Comment: @PaulR !(n & mask ^ mask) would work here?

Comment: Yes, that looks promising, assuming you are allowed to use the logical NOT operator (`!`).

Comment: @PaulR I can, i've got a better grasp of things. thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
int loop(int x) {
    x = x & 0xaaaaaaaa; // Set all even numbered bits in x to zero
    x = x ^ 0xaaaaaaaa; // If all odd numbered bits in x are 1, x becomes zero
    x = !x;             // The operation returns 1 if x is zero - otherwise 0
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Maybe i dont get it, but this does return a value greater then 1, doesnt it?

Comment: Oh i see, because ! is logical not. Clever!

Answer (score 0):

Your code tests all odd bits and returns 1 if all of them are set. You can use this bitmask: ...0101 0101 0101
Which, for 32 bits is 0xAAAAAAAA.
Then you take your value und bitwise-and it. If the result is the same as your mask, it means all bits are set.

```
int testOddBits(int x) {
    return (x & 0xAAAAAAAA) == 0xAAAAAAAA;
}
```

Comment: @PaulR no it isnt, because the return is int, not bool.

Comment: @PaulR i dont have to try, i know programming. The function will return -1431655766 which is the value of 0xAAAAAAAA. If you interpret is as bool, it will be true though, becuase all values other then 0 are true.

Comment: I see the logic of this solution however I would want to avoid using == or ? as given above. Also unless im making a mistake here the loop  above returns 0 multiple times for each iteration which troubles me unless i've made a mistake.

Comment: oh i see, i didnt get you. i though you would suggest return x & 0xAAAAAAAA. You are right, sry.

Comment: @Silverfin Your function does not return multiple times. You can only return once. The function will be aborted, and the single value will be returned.

Comment: @MarioDekena you're correct, I had changed them to print statements which had allowed me to see multiple 0's, my mistake, thank you.

Comment: Funny to see how each_and_every answer in [C] is downvoted even tho it's a correct answer to the question, and may (nor may not) have a small slip. And funny how all these "experts" keep their mouth shut instead of answering, and then nitpick those who do.

Comment: @PaulR mouseover the downvote button and read what it says. It says: "This answer is not useful." Answering the question not exactly doesnt mean it cant be useful. So sad people are such haters nowadays.

Comment: @PaulR i know all that and i got used to it too. I just cant understand it, because i think differently. Lets stop this discussion, this is not a forum ;)

Comment: @RaulR as far as i've understood, the problem is the loop, and `?:` is explained in the link provided by the OP. so I cannot see why Mario's answer is "not helpful", it hints to using a mask to AND with it, rather than using a loop. Let the OP decide if the return type matters or not

Comment: @PaulR chances are high you gonna end up with a lot of downvotes there too. Especially if you would ask how StackOverflow works...